# Free SCM for Matlab 64 bit version on Windows

Tags: windows, matlab, version-control

When Matlab is installed in its 64 bit version, it can use only 64 bit source control systems. **Is there a source control system that's free, works with 64 bit Matlab and runs on Windows?**

It can be a system that supports only one developer. It can be 32 bit itself, if it'll work. It will be installed on the same machine as the Matlab in use, which is a Win7 Ultimate x64 machine.

Comment: What do you mean when you state: When Matlab is installed in its 64 bit version, it can use only 64 bit source control systems. ?  I have 32-bit and 64-bit installations of Matlab, use both 32-bit and 64-bit TortoiseSVN clients on the same server, and have no problems.  What do you know that I don't ?

Comment: @High: That's exactly it. You need a 64 bit client for your SCM for it to work, and I want the server to be on the same machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) using the [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) interface. There is a 64bit windows version available for download. It includes a set of windows shell extentions so it works nicely from the explorer window.

It's easy to set up and use and it's saved me on numerous occasions. Mercurial works well with binary files so MATLAB mat files and fig files can all be placed in version control. I'd say it's essential i you're using guide. In developing GUI's with guide there have been occasions where guide has crashed and was unable to reopen the fig file again. Fortunately a quick roll back in Mercurial to the last previous working version and I was back working again.

To be honest I've never really been that impressed with MATLAB's integration with SCM, it just seems to be a tacked on option rather than integrated. Something like NetBeans shows how you can integrate SCM in the development environment. So I wouldn't try to get MATLAB "to use" SCM rather just use Mercurial (or whatever you choose) alongside MATLAB.

Oh and it's free as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using git to track my matlab code and it's been very useful.  If you do go this route, make a .gitignore file and put the following in it

```
*.asv
*.fig
*.mat
```

The reason for the first one is that you don't want to archive your autogenerated backups.  Since .mat and .fig files can be large and are generally generated by your code, I don't archive them either.  One exception is gui figs;  I create a gui directory and put a new .gitignore file in it with

```
!*.fig
```

which tells git not to ignore .fig files in that directory

Answer (score 1):

For SVN, I have written a [Matlab-GUI](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23508-svngui) for committing (and checking differences in) code for when I'm too lazy to launch another application to commit my changes (or for when there is no nice, free client, like on OS X).

You could do something similar for any other version control system, and then you don't need to worry about whether Matlab supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using [Subversion](http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/resources/how-to-guides/development-environment-setup/subversion) or [Git](http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/resources/how-to-guides/development-environment-setup/git), which are tried-and-true, general-purpose SCMs.

Comment: Or http://mercurial.selenic.com/

Comment: Do you know if Matlab recognizes their clients? And 64 bit Matlab?

Comment: @Asaf, Matlab files are just plaintext files ending in ".m". So, SVN and Git will work just fine. In fact, for one of my university courses, we are storing Matlab files in Subversion. By the way, thanks for the downvote.

Comment: Don't forget *.mat and *.fig files are actually binary format so you need an SCM that can handle them cleanly and efficiently.

Comment: @Asaf R - No, matlab doesn't recognize them.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks. I don't know who downvoted you, but since there's no explanation, I upvoted to balance it.

Comment: @Asaf, sorry for accusing you.

Comment: @Adrian, Subversion and Git handle binary files just fine... true, it isn't as efficient as text files, but I have yet to hear of an SCM that is optimized for binary files. And, in any project, there are usually way more source code files than binary data files.