# How do you manage versions?

Tags: git, matlab, revision-history

I am a self-trained programmer (analytical chemist by training, now more akin to a bioinformatician and computational biologist). My code alternates between one-off work that may not be used more than a handful of times, to code that is constantly building on top of itself or other modules I have written. I am the only one working on this code, but I work on it from many locations. For this reason, I use dropbox to keep all of my projects synced. Problem is that currently when I make major changes to a file, I either make notes within the file and comment out the old section or simply add a counter to the file name (v1, v2, etc). This gets messy both within my code and within my directory.

I realized this is not the most effective way to keep track of versions, but when it is just me, it is very quick for me to move between files, debugging or improving, and in the event I need to go back a version, either the 'previous versions' within Windows works, or  Dropbox keeps versions. This is opposed to having to commit, pull, branch, etc. with something like Git-hub.

Can anyone recommend a better workflow, again, for a single person to keep track of code? Instead of keeping all the v1, v2, etc, it would be nice to have a record of them somewhere, easy comparisons to see changes, and the ability to use them if needed.

Comment: No experience with such systems, no recommendation, but I want to point out that Matlab has support for different source control systems. See "Preferences / General / Source Control".

Comment: Even I work similarly. I would like to know a better workflow too.

Comment: I feel pretty stupid for missing that. I had assumed it was only part of a package/toolbox I don't use (Simulink). Says I need to find a 64-bit source control system, which there are some to try. I also ran across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506314/free-scm-for-matlab-64-bit-version-on-windows) older post. But is this the best route to go (running within matlab) as opposed to outside of matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd really recommend you to start using a distributed version control system (DVCS), such as [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

You wouldn't need to stop using Dropbox, but rather turn your shared code folder into a repository that allows you to frequently commit any changes that matter.

If you ever need to collaborate, you can look into hosting solutions like [Github](https://github.com/) or [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), but you could just as easily share your Dropbox folder with other collaborators.

This way you would get a relatively simple yet powerful workflow.

Comment: So in this case, would I simply commit changes from the dropbox folder to the GIT repository at some frequency (say end of business each day)? If I needed to check back on a previous version, I could go through Git, but otherwise, I would just be working from the same folder as always? Secondly, would this help me get around my excessive version naming scheme? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, you'd be hosting the entire git repository on your Dropbox shared folder, so you would be able to commit to the repository from any of your computers. Git will keep all historical information inside the .git/ sub-folder, while the current state of your code are the other files in the folder, as usual. You wouldn't need to track versions in the filename, because now you can easily check out earlier versions of your code when necessary.

Comment: One thing you'll have to wrap your head around is that checking out a previous version from history will replace the visible files in the folder with the state of your code from that version. It won't allow you to do this unless you have committed all current changes, so that you don't lose them (instead of formally committing them, you could also temporary stash your latest changes). Once you're done checking out or testing the previous version, you would be able to easily check out the latest version and continue your work.

Comment: http://gitref.org/ is a good primer on Git that should help you understand how it works. You will probably want to use a GUI for day to day operations: http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis.

Comment: Everyone, I really appreciate the advice and resources. I think this proposed setup will work perfectly and will also help me become better at working with Git, which will translate well if I need to work with other programmers on larger projects. Thanks.